# simplifying long expressions in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, simplification

I'm doing some mathematical modelling and couldn't simplify the following expression result

[image: Expression]

into its simplified form like this

[image: Desired Result]

I'm new with sympy and already tried the combinations of simplify, expand, cancel, collect methods... but nothing works.

What's the best way to simplify long expressions?

P.S. Capital Delta Δ in the second formula is the small delta δ in the first expression.

Comment: A good place to start would be to define the original expression and the desired result in code, and call simplify on the difference to see if you get 0. Right now, capital delta occurs in the result but not in the input. It is unclear how sympy would figure that out without context.

Comment: Oh, Capital delta is represented as small delta in my input. cause i couldn't figured out how to write the Capital one yet. As for the result, its the same.

Comment: Did you try using `.apart` for partial fractions? Another idea is to check if Wolfram Alpha / Mathematica gives you the desired result. If not, automatic simplification with sympy might be hard.

Comment: It's better to show simple code that creates the expression (use repr) with all imports and symbols defined. I think `apart` will get you some of the way and something like `collect` applying `factor` to the coefficients.

Comment: Trust but verify -- it would be assuring (and helpful) to show the work for which `start.equals(finish) == True` where start is your starting expression and finish is the final expression desired.